# picture not displaying laravel 8

Tags: image, laravel-8

This is my code

AdminAddProductComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;
use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AdminAddProductComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $name;
    public $slug;
    
    public $short_description;
    public $description;
    public $regular_price;
    public $sale_price;
    public $SKU;
    public $stock_status;
    public $featured;
    public $quantity;
    public $image;
    public $category_id;
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->stock_status = 'instock';
        $this->featured = 0;
    }

    public function generateSlug()
    {
        $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = $this->name;
        $product->slug = $this->slug;
        $product->short_description = $this->short_description;
        $product->description = $this->description;
        $product->regular_price = $this->regular_price;
        $product->sale_price = $this->sale_price;
        $product->SKU = $this->SKU;
        $product->stock_status = $this->stock_status;
        $product->featured = $this->featured;
        $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
        $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'.$this->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('products',$imageName);
        $product->image = $imageName;
        $product->category_id = $this->category_id;
        $product->save();
        session()->flash('message','Product has been created successfully!');
        
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories=Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-product-component',['categories'=>$categories])->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

admin-add-product-component.blade.php

```
<div>
    <div class="container"style="padding:30px 0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Add New Product
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="{{route('admin.products')}}"class="btn btn-success pull-right">All Products</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if(Session::has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                        @endif
                        <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"wire:submit.prevent="addProduct">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="name"wire:keyup="generateSlug"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Slug</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Slug" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="slug"/>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Short Description"wire:model="short_description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Description"wire:model="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Regular Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular Price" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="regular_price"/>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sale Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Sale Price" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="sale_price"/>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SKU</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="SKU"/>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Stock</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control"wire:model="stock_status">
                                        <option value="instock">InStock</option>
                                        <option value="outofstock">Out of Stock</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Featured</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control"wire:model="featured">
                                        <option value="0">No</option>
                                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control input-md"wire:model="quantity"/>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Product image</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="file" class="input-file"wire:model="image"/>
                                    @if($image)
                                        <img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}"width="120"/>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control"wire:model="category_id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>    
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                           
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why it's not working.. I mean the picture cant display on my Image show product page...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcGAM05UMwA&list=PLz_YkiqIHesvPtvLl2Wz5FtuW44dBt199&index=18&ab_channel=SurfsideMedia I follow this video<<< it just I dont know why my picture not showing out. it show the alt="picture" things

Comment: please add spaces between variables. like this `<img src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}" width="120"/>`

Comment: it still not working....

Comment: Can you check if the URL is added to the image tag? If so, can you open it in the browser directly? Does the image load?

Answer (score 0):

add `use Livewire\Carbon;` instead of usu carbo

Comment: What is "usu carbo"?